# Porque função .text() em jQuery não tem o comportamento esperado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a fazer um desenvolvimento na web, para um site em joomla.

Quando faço:

```
jQuery('.encomendas tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {                
    $(this).toggleClass('diminuir');
    if ($(this).hasClass('diminuir'))
        $(this).innerHTML = '-';
    else
        $(this).innerHTML = '+';

    // ...
});
```

Isto funciona, ou seja, seleciono um elemento em jQuery e altero o valor da propriedade `innerHTML` do JavaScript.

Antes estava a usar o método `.text()`

```
$(this).toggleClass('diminuir');
if ($(this).hasClass('diminuir'))
    $(this).text('-');
else
    $(this).text('+');
```

Obtinha sempre o erro,

> uncaught typeerror $(...).text is not a function

Perdi horas a tentar compreender este comportamento, sem resultado. Até que tentei usar estupidamente o `innerHTML` e funcionou.

O que está errado?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada na sua pergunta. O `.innerHTML` não funciona com objetos jQuery, e o `.text()` deveria funcionar, já que ele é um método desde a primeira versão do jQuery.

Comment: AP, note que eu editei sua publicação e melhorei a formatação da mesma. Quando for postar uma nova pergunta/resposta atente à formatação da mesma, isso ajuda quem está lendo. No [meta] existem guias de formatação bem interessantes, recomendo a leitura.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem absolutamente nada de errado. Note que, se você pretende alterar o HTML do elemento, a função que deve usar é `html()` e não  `text()`.

Eu estou estranhando você conseguir usar o campo `innerHTML` num elemento jQuery. Eu estou um pouco enferrujado, mas acredito que isso não deveria ser possível, porque um elemento jQuery não é a mesma coisa que o elemento DOM "cru".

Você precisa se certificar que `$(this)` é realmente um elemento jQuery.

Veja um exemplo análogo ao seu abaixo. Incluindo um teste do campo `innerHTML`.

```js
$('.encomendas tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {       
    $(this).text('+')
})

$('.encomendas tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control2', function () {           
    $(this).html('++')    
})

$('.teste').on('click', function () {           
    console.log($(this).innerHTML)
    console.log($(this).get(0).innerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class='encomendas'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='details-control'>Item 1 - A</td>
    <td class='details-control2'>Item 1 - B</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<button class='teste'>Teste innerHTML</button>
```

Comment: É eu estava lendo outras coisas aqui, o text() tem muito mais coisa do que só trocar um texto... Apesar que em algumas versões do jQuery pode dar o problema com o método, ou se quiser interagir com um input, que eu acho que não é o caso dele

Comment: @hugocsl Pois é, eu vi que não é muito preto no branco, mas tentei reproduzir o caso do AP e pareceu normal. Inclusive estranhei ele usar `innerHTML` num objeto jQuery porque isso não deveria ser possível. Imagino que haja outra lib reescrevendo o `$`

Comment: Boa explicação. Eu também não queria acreditar, mas a verdade é que o innerHTML está a funcionar num elemento jQuery.

Comment: quando usava .html() dá o mesmo erro. uncaught typeerror $(...).text is not a function

Comment: @PedroCorreia Provavelmente tem alguma coisa reescrevendo o `$`, tente usando `jQuery(this).`